# self.presentingViewController is not the one which should be?

Tags: ios

[image]

So in a class hierarchy like the one in the screenshot:

- VC1 is a `UITabBarController`
- VC2 is a `UINavigationController`
- VC3 is a details `UIViewController`
- VC4 is a `UINavigationController`
- VC5 is a details `UIViewController`

In VC3 the press of a button presents VC4 **modally** which pushes VC5. Now VC5's `presentingViewController` is VC1, the `UITabBarController`.

Shouldn't it be VC3? Because that's the one who presented VC4(which is VC5's nav controller) modally. Or in other words, how can one access VC3's instance from the modally pushed VC5?

Comment: When VC4 is presented, is the tab bar still visible or not?

Comment: @rmaddy no, it is not.

Comment: Try setting `modalPresentationStyle` of VC4 to `.currentContext`. Does that change the result?

Comment: @rmaddy now the `presentingViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, but it's not VC4, I believe is VC2.